# Javascript runtime optimizing array modifications

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

I have a problem optimizing the runtime for my code. Ideally, what I'm trying to achieve is that all the operations below is performed in a single loop, so that I don't have to run through the dataset many times as I'm doing now (very large dataset!)

The code is transforming aggData to an array on the following format: [0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 43, 4: 121, 5: 0, ....], where each number represents a year in the interval, if the interval is (1800-2020) 0 will represent the count for 1800, 1 will be 1801 and so on ..

aggData is an array of objects on the following format: `{key_as_string: "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", key: -2208988800000, doc_count: 17}`. The start-year is the first year with a doc_count higher than 0.

Below I provide a description of what each step does as the code is now:

Here I am changing the format of each object in the list to be : {year: number, count: number}

```
 const formatAggData = aggData
        .map((item: AggData) => {
            return { year: moment(item.key_as_string).year(), count: item.doc_count };
        });
```

This function creates an array of objects with the from as start year and to as end year, if the year already exists in existingArray it uses the count from there, if not it sets count to 0.

```
    function fillYears(from: number, to: number, existingArray: YearCount[]) {
        const existingObject: { [year: string]: number } = { year: null };
        existingArray.map((x: YearCount) => (existingObject[x.year] = x.count));

        const yearsArray = [];
        for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            yearsArray.push({
                year: i,
                count: existingObject[i] || 0,
            });
        }

        return yearsArray;
    }
```

Converts year values to count-values, where the first year in the list will be 0 with the corresponding value, second will be 1 with corresponding value and so on..

```
    const resultList = fillYears(min, max, formatAggData).map(
        (item: YearCount) => item.count,
    );
```

Comment: "*very large dataset!*" - where is that data coming from? What part of your code actually is the slow operation (have you profiled it)? Also it looks like your data set never has more than 220 items (years 1800 to 2020), so that's not "large".

Comment: Is the data sorted by year? In that case, you shouldn't need to use that `existingObject` lookup at all.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details! The data is returned from an ElasticSearch date histogram aggregation, and yes, the data is sorted by year. @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at you code. can't you do it like this? it looks like you don't need to know the year at this moment

```
function fillYears(from: number, to:number, existingYears: YearCount[]) {
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
      yearsArray.push({
          year: i,
          count: existingYears[i].doc_count || 0,
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks a lot! 
The only thing I had to change was this:   
count: existingArray[i - from]?.count || 0,
(Because the from parameter is year and not starting at 0)